# How to load data in Telerik radgrid after the page is loaded using ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I am using Telerik radgrid in an asp.net project. Currently we bind the data to the grid on pageload event, which takes a lot of time and the page will load on browser after loading all data.

How we can load page first and after that load data in Telerik radgrid?

Answer (score 0):

Use client-side data binding. Here is one guide http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/client-side/client-data-source-binding/defaultcs.aspx